# Using of ubiquitous language in application services arguments

Tags: service, parameters, arguments, domain-driven-design

The ubiquitous language (UL) is used in a whole bounded context, both the domain model and the application layer right? Ok. Then the name of the methods of an application service belongs to the UL. But the arguments of the method, as domain objects shouldn't be expose to the users, won't (cannot) be terms from the UL. If you used UL vocabulary to name method args, then you would be exposing domain objects outside the application.

How do you explain this contradiction about naming application services parameters?

Maybe the question seems a little bit philosophical, but so is DDD, it's a philosophy on software development, and it is based on the UL.

UPDATE

Someone asked for an example, not just philosophy. Well let's say our domain is about a shop selling products. One method of an application service could be:

addProductToShoppingCart ( Product product, ShoppingCart shoppingCart );

But Product and ShoppingCart are entities/value objects of the domain model, and we shouldn't expose it to clients.

So args should be DTOs or primitive types. But such types don't belong to the UL. Product and ShoppingCart do belong to the UL and should be the args of the method, but by doing it you break the rule of exposing domain to clients.

Comment: "But Product and ShoppingCart are entities/value objects of the domain model, and we shouldn't expose it to clients." - Why? If we don't expose the "domain", what are we supposed to expose? Non-domain, i.e. technical objects?

Comment: According to DDD, if I don't missunderstood it, you can expose domain enities/value objects to client, but you shouldn't... it isn't "mandatory" but a good practice I think. Vaughn Vernon for example use primitives, not domain objects. Application layer is the direct client of domain model and protects it from the outside, it maps dtos/primitive types into domain objects and viceversa. It exposes state, not the whole objects

Comment: Vaughn Vernon has books about the subject, I don't, so as far as authority goes I guess he wins. Still, I do not agree with him at all on his interpretation. I've done architectures like that a lot, and they are not maintainable. Or rather, there are more maintainable alternatives, which involve sticking to the domain, and not introducing technical objects (or layers even) at  all.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by technical objects? DTOs? I dont agree when you say that sticking to the domain is more mantenible than to have clients decoupled from the domain. Is right the opposite: if domain changes you would have to change every client. OTH with clients decoupled from the domain, you would have to change just the application layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the application service layer should strive to reflect the UL as much as it can without leaking details from the domain model technical solution. In other words, you want the application service public API to be expressed using terms of the ubiquitous language, but you do not want the client code to be couple on the domain model layer.

> "If you used UL vocabulary to name method args, then you would be exposing domain objects outside the application."

That's a misconception: method arguments should be named using UL terms where you can, but argument types shouldn't leverage types defined in the domain package. This is for technical reasons only as that segregation lets you change the domain model independently from the public application's API.

Comment: "then you're not using the UL well". Well, you would most likely name the argument `productId` actually, and that's as much aligned with the UL as it can be. If you named the argument `thing` or `thingId` then yeah you wouldn't follow the UL as closely as you could. It's a question of trade-offs. There's no perfect solution.

Comment: Yeah, well the "perfect" (purist) solution maybe is using id in args and name of the method.... "addProductOfProductIdToShoppingCartOfShoppingCardId ( ProductId productId, ShoppingCartId shoppingCartId )... but this is too much verbose, I dont think any domain expert talked this way. I bet for "addProductToShoppingCart ( ProductId productId, ShoppingCartId shoppingCartId )"

Comment: Even this way I should expose ids, which are domain objects as well. As you said there is no perfect solution if I dont wanna expose any domain object, as I have to name an arg using the UL, but the arg type isnt a domain type. The arg would be "String productId". From my point of view DDD fails here.

Comment: @choquero70 The important aspect is to honor the UL in the **domain layer**. The rest is **just plumbing**. You're splitting hairs here and I'm not even sure what's your question anymore? I mean, going down your train of thoughts... does the HTTP protocol follows the UL? What about the TCP/IP protocol?

Comment: I think that application layer should follow UL, because it is the UC boundary and it is the direct client of domain model. But http, tcp/ip or whatever dont have anything to do with UL, they are technology stuff outside the application. So they are not in my train of thoughts. Maybe I'm too purist and philosophical, and maybe I'm wrong thinking that application services following the UL is important and it's not just plumbing. Anyway, question is over. Thanks for your opinion and for wasting your time with this. Regards.

Comment: @choquero70 I also think you should try to make use of the UL as much as you can even in the application layer. Naming is not rendered useless just because you can't leverage domain types.

Answer (score 0):

An example would be much better to discuss than just the "philosophy". But..

The contradiction is that most DDD designs *do not* in fact follow the UL rigorously enough. Look at almost any publicly available "DDD" design, for example [Vaughn Vernon's Github repository](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples).

The "Domain" (i.e. Value Objects and Entities) usually are modeled as data-only "objects", with little if any business logic. Right there the method names already left the UL and are purely in technical terrain (setters, getters usually).

Same with Services. Services are *not* part of the "Domain" at all. Try telling a business person that you've implemented a `PasswordService`, I guarantee a blank stare back. Services are also purely technical on the outside, with some business-related methods in them, that could actually belong to some Value Object or Entity.

So, while I agree with the "philosophy" part, the building blocks defined by Eric Evans as used today are far from an optimal implementation of that philosophy.

Take a look at my presentation about exactly this issue: https://speakerdeck.com/robertbraeutigam/object-oriented-domain-driven-design

Comment: Regarding the mentioned presentation and the refactoring example for group membership: your solution failed to recognize that group members could be other groups, which at this points needs to perform IO to fetch members, hence the reason why Vaughn modeled this use case with the help of a service. You could always have done `group.hasMember(potentialMember, groupMembershipResolver)`, but then it implies your domain is not "pure" and can perform IO indirectly.

Comment: I kept on reading... the persistence option #1 makes no sense at all. Your domain logic now becomes lost in infrastructural details and you can't unit test it. The persistence option #2 also leaks infrastructural details in the domain. It's all a question of trade-offs, but the suggestions are far worst than most repository pattern implementations.

Comment: @plalx You're right, the membership check is separated because the design wants to separate the "IO" from `Group`. This is however completely arbitrary. It's a problem the design made, and then solved with a workaround by leaving the "domain". It's wrong. I don't care (and you shouldn't either) how a `Group` determines whether something is a member or not. Maybe it does use some collaborators, maybe it just has to check it's instance variables. Why should it matter?

Comment: Well, most DDD purists would argue against injecting services of any kind in entities because services aren't part of the entities state and it makes testability much harder. If you dont have any service injection then you also have no mocks & stubs needed to test your domain model and your persistence strategy also doesn't have to care about service injection. Most developers that I know of tend to agree that it's a better trade-off to remove all kind of IO from domain objects.